# line exceeds margin in cover letter

Tags: line-breaking, newlfm

I used `newlfm` to create a cover letter. However after I made some pieces of text bold, italics and underlined, some lines exceeded the margin. I then used `\sloppy`. Still, there is one line that juts out of the margin. 
How can I correct this error, please?

In response to Christian Hupfer's comment, here's a MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm} % Extra options: 'sigleft' for a left-aligned signature, 'stdletternofrom' to remove the from address, 'letterpaper' for US letter paper - consult the newlfm class manual for more options

\usepackage{charter} % Use the Charter font for the document text
\sloppy
\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.75in}{\vspace{0.5in}
\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{logo.png}}} % Company/institution logo at the top left of the page
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}

\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt} % Slightly decrease the height of the signature field
\newlfmP{addrfromphone} % Print a phone number under the sender's address
\newlfmP{addrfromemail} % Print an email address under the sender's address
\PhrPhone{Phone} % Customize the "Telephone" text
\PhrEmail{Email} % Customize the "E-mail" text

\lthUiuc % Print the company/institution logo

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\namefrom{John Smith} % Name

\addrfrom{
\today\\[12pt] % Date
123 Broadway \\ % Address
City, State 12345
}

\phonefrom{(000) 111-1111} % Phone number

\emailfrom{john@smith.com} % Email address

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDRESSEE AND GREETING/CLOSING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\greetto{Dear Mrs. Smith,} % Greeting text
\closeline{Sincerely yours,} % Closing text

\nameto{Mrs. Jane Smith} % Addressee of the letter above the to address

\addrto{
Recruitment Officer \\ % To address
The Corporation \\
123 Pleasant Lane \\
City, State 12345
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LETTER CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PARAGRAPH ONE: State the reason for the letter, name the position or type of work you are applying for and identify the source from which you learned of the opening (i.e. career development center, newspaper, employment service, personal contact).

PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, its products, services - above all, stress what you can do for the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate for the position. If you have practical work experience, point out specific achievements or unique qualifications. \underline{\textbf{\textit{Try not to repeat the same information the reader will find in the resume. Refer the reader to the enclosed resume or application which summarizes your qualifications, training, and experiences}}}. The purpose of this section is to strengthen your resume by providing details which bring your experiences to life. 

PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and indicate your flexibility as to the time and place. Repeat your phone number in the letter and offer assistance to help in a speedy response. For example, state that you will be in the city where the company is located on a certain date and would like to set up an interview. Alternatively, state that you will call on a certain date to set up an interview. End the letter by thanking the employer for taking time to consider your credentials. 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks very much. Please find the MWE above. Cheers

Comment: Simply: don't use `\underline`.

Comment: Add the [`soul` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul) to your document preamble (`\usepackage{soul}`) and use `\ul` instead of `\underline`. See [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KW8pu.png).

Comment: @Werner: Thanks very much! You guys are the best!